# This site can’t be reached when generating excel with oho excel in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

it is running perfect yesterday but today it generates:

> This site can't be reached.

This is my code:

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: what does "This site can’t be reached" mean? what actually happens?

Comment: When trying to generate excel report the url gose to This site can’t be reached page and The webpage at www.example.com/route.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE This happends.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Have you enhanced the error reporting to see whether PHP throws any notices? Have you had a look into your server's error log to see whether a fatal error was reported?

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: yes my server is running perfectly, and yes i debug it i did not saw any error

Comment: How did you debug it? And is there really nothing written to any error log?

Comment: i checked my data is perfect and all the report are generated perfectly till yesterday so code is going well i am printing all errors with error reporting but nothing found.there is another way to debug it?

Comment: Hello, ezad. Welcome to the community! There are other ways to debug. For example, can you check at the apache log file